Can't Request permissions for Instagram Basic Display API
I've built an app using the Instagram Basic Display API, added a few test Instagram accounts, and everything is working fine. Now, I'm trying to submit the app for review, but I'm running into a problem.
I need the permissions instagram_graph_user_profile and instagram_graph_user_media to use the API with real accounts in production. However, when I go to request advanced access for these permissions, the "Request Advanced access" button is greyed out, with the message "This is not available in advanced access."
I'm confused because I thought the whole point was to submit the app for review to get these permissions, right? Without them, I'm unable to authenticate real users and getting an OAuthException when trying to log in with an account that isn't a test account.
I've already contacted Instagram support but haven't gotten a reply yet. Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong here or what steps I can take to fix this? Is there something I'm missing in the process?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
P.S: My business is verified.


We're having the same issue

Same issue here..

Instagram Basic Display API was deprecated on 4th September 2024 and will be discontinued on 4th December 2024. They announced it in a post recently.
Most likely that's why they are not onboarding new users.

Is there an alternative available already? Our use case is that we want to fetch user media (Videos, Reels etc) for public Instagram Business accounts.

Was reviewing Instagram API with Instagram Login, but didn't find anything particularly for this use case.

Oh, In that case I also do not know of any other alternative. Do let us know as well if you find something especially for all Instagram accounts including personal ones

Hey, we are having the same issue. So basically they are shutting down the Basic Display API without any other alternative? Is it possible to fetch user media with the Instagram API? (I can't seem to find a valuable answer)

There is not solution for personal Instagram accounts. Looks like Meta is afraid of potential new social apps building on top of Instagram APIs

You can for business use new API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-instagram-login there  is scope called instagram_business_content_publishing, this should work (I mean, should.. I do not have time to try it :D)
